# Custom class methods not recognized by Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have wrote the following custom class:

**AKRelativeDates.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSDate-Utilities.h"

@interface AKRelativeDates

- (NSString *)relativeDateFromDate:(NSDate *)date in24hFormat:(BOOL)in24hFormat capitalized:(BOOL)capitalized;

@end
```

**AKRelativeDates.m**

```
#import "AKRelativeDates.h"

@implementation AKRelativeDates

- (NSString *)relativeDateFromDate:(NSDate *)date in24hFormat:(BOOL)in24hFormat capitalized:(BOOL)capitalized
{
    // method implementation removed
    return @"test";
}

@end
```

I have imported the header file, the class is recognized, but the method isn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see date, in24hFormat etc...  Declared anywhere in your header file.  I see them declared in your method but you have to declare them directly in your header file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"?  Are you getting warnings in code that uses the method?

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, I get the following warning: 'AKRelativeDates' may not respond to '+relativeDateFromDate:in24hFormat:capitalized:', plus another one, that the method is not found, return type defaults to 'id'. Xcode code completion does not suggest this method either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing some things from your header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSDate-Utilities.h"

@interface AKRelativeDates : NSObject    //Follow the class name with the superclass.

{
    //Now enclose any class objects if any - if none then brackets are optional
}

//And now time for the method declarations:

- (NSString *)relativeDateFromDate:(NSDate *)date in24hFormat:(BOOL)in24hFormat capitalized:(BOOL)capitalized;

@end
```

Also, if it is a class method (i.e. you don't want to create the object before using this method) then replace the '-' with '+'

Comment: Brackets are only necessary if the class declares instance variables.

Comment: @Bavarious that I didn't know :) Have changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, the '+' sign. That way it does get recognized, although it crashes... Including the superclass (NSObject) was also necessary, the brackets are optional, though.

Answer (score 1):

As Jordan says, your header is incomplete.

However, you are also omitting to import it into the source code file where you use the method.

Comment: I have not included the source code where I was trying to use it.. I did specify though that the header was imported there.

Answer (score 0):

> @JeremyP Yes, I get the following warning: 'AKRelativeDates' may not respond to '**+relativeDateFromDate:in24hFormat:capitalized:**', plus another one, that the method is not found, return type defaults to 'id'. Xcode code completion does not suggest this method either

Base on your reply, you are probably using it this way:

```
[AKRelativeDates relativeDateFromDate:theDate in24hFormat:theIn24hFormat capitalized:theCapitalized];
```

You are accessing the method from class, but you declared the method as an instance method. @Jordan has pointed you the right answer in his last sentence. I'm just trying to be more specific.

Change the - to + in both .h and .m file, like this:

```
+ (NSString *)relativeDateFromDate:(NSDate *)date in24hFormat:(BOOL)in24hFormat capitalized:(BOOL)capitalized
```

Comment: The difference in the error message was because I've been trying to change a few things in Xcode in the meanwhile; the problem was in fact with the -/+ sign, as I intended to create this method to use directly, without instantiating an object before.